# How to create a bunch of tiny equal holes in a curved plane

Tags: modeling, materials

I'm currently working on recreating this type of material on blender but I'm not sure how to make this many small holes on a curved plane. Right now in my project I have a plane that's the same shape as the example but without the holes and I'm unsure how to add those holes. Any help would be much appreciated :)

thanks.

[image: Material Example]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223648/35559)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill/41007#41007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working X across, Z up.

- Enable the shipped add-on 'Add Mesh: Extra Objects'.
- Add a 'Honeycomb' object with the desired number and size of hexes.

[image]

The following steps are optional, in your case, because another part is overlapping the edges of your grid..

- If necessary, select the appropriate outside perimeter edges, and <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> extrude them, before <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, straightening them.
- With Snap set to 'Vertex and 'Active', snap the corner diagonals together, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut in some transitional loops.

Give the sheet modifiers..

- *Solidify* (outwards)
- *Bevel* (by a high angle, tiny 1-segment)
- *Simple Deform > Bend*
- A level of *Subdivision Surface*.

[image]

If the curve is not right for you, you could, say, duplicate a bit of the surrounding geometry, convert that to a curve, and use a *Curve* modifier to deform the mesh along that, instead of the *Simple Deform*.

Comment: My holes are a bit small. 'Honeycomb' gives you the option to make them bigger.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get this is like so:

1. add a plane and subdivide it

[image]

2. press ctrl-b to bevel it like so

[image]

3. change bevel settings like so:

affect: vertices
change shape until it is a circle

[image]

[image]

4. select the most inner vertex of the circle

[image]

5. select more

[image]

6. select similar like this:

[image]

7. hit x -> delete vertices

[image]

8. Tab -> object mode
9. add simple deform modifier, bend, y

[image]

10. tab -> edit mode -> A -> select all

[image]

11. G->X -> move to right (y line left from plane)

[image]

12. R->X -> 90 and change axis on modifier to z

[image]

result:

[image]