# Why is my boolean modifier ignoring the top of this shape?

Tags: modifiers

I've stacked boolean on top of boolean on top of boolean to get to this shape:

[image: Image of the shape I've reached]

However, there should be some other cutouts on top, and it's ignoring them...

[image: No cutouts on top showing, even though they exist.]

Sharing the blender file... https://gofile.io/d/Bl8FGQ

not sure if someone can figure out why there's no nice cutouts.

**What I want is to have a perimeter like the bottom, but on top... so there should be tiny holes up top, I would think?**

Comment: That is possibly the worst most error prone way to achieve this. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67334/how-to-turn-my-honeycomb-pattern-into-the-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223591/honeycomb-boolean-around-cylinder

Comment: ...Thanks. I used the second way in the first link you sent... because it seemed a lot faster and easier. I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.